# How to deploy my Apache Zookeeper image to AWS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, apache-zookeeper

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPUhD.png)

#### How can I deploy my application (3 microservices and an Apache Zookeeper docker image) to AWS?

Can I have an docker image running in AWS? Does it have any cost included?
All 3 microservice applications depends on my Apache Zookeeper docker image, so that they can retrieve information from each other.

I just don't know how to deploy this applications on AWS. Should I deploy each application on an independent instance?

Thank you!

Comment: AWS ECS is their response to docker and EKS is K8

Answer (score 1):

You can run all 3 micro services and your zookeeper docker container in a single EC2 instance if that's all you prefer (for testing of course). If you want to run a production scale application, I believe you need more than just one EC2 instance. You might also want to think about deploying them in different AZs and also keep zookeeper (source of truth) running in a separate subnet to separate applications and zookeeper.

Also, you can explore EKS if your micro services are containerized.